# Join query using between

Tags: join, dlookup

I have made this work before, but I can not find it and do not remember how.

```
SELECT tblMyData.ID, tblMyData.LineNum, tblBudgetRange.[Budget Name] 
FROM tblMyData 
INNER JOIN tblBudgetRange 
ON tblMyData.LineNum Between ([tblBudgetRange].[fromLine]) And ([tblBudgetRange].[toLine]);
```

I also tried `DLookUp("BudgetName","tblBudgetRange", [LineNum] & "Between fromLine and toLine"`.

Comment: Please tag your quesrtion with the database you are running: mysql, sql-server, oracle...?

Comment: You would probably also need to show some sample data and desired results (as tabular text), and help us better understand your problem. What happens when you run your code? What is not working as you would like?